# Java (Removing a 'keyword' from the alphabet)

Tags: java, character

so I want to remove modifiedKeyword from the alphabet (PLAIN_ALPHA used as the constant)

```
private String removeKeyword(String modifiedKeyword){
  int wordLength = modifiedKeyword.length();
  int letterPosition;
  int alphabetPosition;
  String modifiedAlphabet = "";
  final String PLAIN_ALPHA = "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  for (alphabetPosition=0; alphabetPosition<=26; letterPosition++){
    boolean shouldBeDeleted = false;
    char alphabetLetter = PLAIN_ALPHA.charAt(alphabetPosition);
    for (letterPosition=0; letterPosition>wordLength; letterPosition++){
      char keywordLetter = modifiedKeyword.charAt(letterPosition);
      if (alphabetLetter == keywordLetter) { shouldBeDeleted = true;}
      modifiedAlphabet += alphabetLetter;
    }



  }

  return modifiedAlphabet;
}
```

for some reason when I Run it, it wouldnt execute but would just keep on loading (the mouse cursor shows loading animation) forever. Can u guys spot any errors that I mustve missed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (alphabetPosition=0; alphabetPosition<=26; letterPosition++){
```

you are never increasing the counter variable `alphabetPosition` so your code is running in an infinite loop.

**Edit:**

there's also an easier way to do this using [String#replaceAll(,String, String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
private String removeKeyword(String modifiedKeyword){
    final String PLAIN_ALPHA = "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //try to extract this as a constant for cleaner code
    String result = PLAIN_ALPHA.replaceAll(modifiedKeyword, "");

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I dont think we are allowed to use that String method..... They expect us to do this using only loops and the basic String methods

Comment: but you could use my method for automated testing ;-)

Comment: yup, I used it and it worked haha. Although I don't think theyd be happy to see me using a method they didnt teach. sigh. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (alphabetPosition=0; alphabetPosition<=26; letterPosition++){
```

You're incrementing another variable than the one you've initialized. (In fact, you never increment alphabetPosition).

```
for (letterPosition=0; letterPosition>wordLength; letterPosition++){
```

letterPosition may not be superior than you're word length, right ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I fixed those but for some reason it isnt returning anything http://pastebin.com/3cdU43c7

Comment: I've checked your code, there is an error : `if (shouldBeDeleted == false)` instead of one =
So if I understand, your function is supposed to remove the characters provided by the string from the alphabet ?

Comment: Actually, I intend the function to 'add' the characters that arent in the keyword to the 'modeified Alphabet'.

Answer (score 0):

You should always double-check your loops when these things occur, it's most likely an endless loop. `alphabetPosition` is always 0 in your case, never reaching 27:

```
for (alphabetPosition=0; alphabetPosition<=26; letterPosition++){
```

Comment: Hi, I fixed those errors out, but for some reason it's not returning any values...Thanks for the reply though. http://pastebin.com/3cdU43c7